How can I skip a processors.exec for a specific output?
I would like to collect MQTT packets with Telegraf and store them in a Postgres DB. In addition, I would like to store certain values in an InfluxDB. I have the following config files:
telegraf_influx.conf:
[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
  servers = ["mqtt://localhost:1883"]
  topics = ["demo1"]
  qos = 0
  client_id = "telegraf"
  data_format = "json"
  name_override = "mqtt_raw"
  json_string_fields = ["timestamp*"]
  tag_keys = ["tag1", "tag2"]

[[processors.execd]]
  command = ["python","./influx.py"]
  
[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
  urls = ["http://localhost:8086"]
  token= "apikey"
  organization = "demo"
  bucket = "bucket-1"

telegraf_postgres.conf:
[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
  servers = ["mqtt://localhost:1883"]
  topics = ["demo1"]
  qos = 0
  client_id = "telegraf"
  data_format = "json"
  name_override = "mqtt_raw"
  json_string_fields = ["*"]
  tag_keys = ["tag1", "tag2"]
  

[[outputs.postgresql]]
  connection = "host=localhost user=postgres_user password=postgres_password sslmode=disable dbname=postgres_1"
  timestamp_column_type = "timestamp with time zone"  
  fields_as_jsonb = true
  tags_as_jsonb = false
  create_templates = [
    '''
    CREATE TABLE {{ .table }} ("id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, {{ .columns }});
    ''',
  ]

If I want to start both config files as two telegraf service, the second service fails with the MQTT connection. Can I do both with just one Telegraf instance, but only pre-process the data for InfluxDB via processor?
Or how is this usually solved?
